# opencv Ignore some object on frame

Tags: c++, opencv

I have webcam on street and i want to track every car moved Infront camera 
i used for this background Substration 
now i just want idea or method on opencv help me to  Ignore some object 
I mean track every thing in street and Ignore one object its  human 
Iam new on opencv

what i try its

```
Ptr<BackgroundSubtractor> pMOG2;
pMOG2 = createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
```

.....   to the end of code

i use  background Substration because its track every thing move infront it 
any idea for ignore human only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want to ignore people objects, you should first know which objects are people, and which are not-people.

Usually to find people in an image (or video stream), you use a people detector. You can do it with [HogDescriptor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/object_detection.html)

```
HOGDescriptor hog;
hog.setSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector());
```

> An example applying the HOG descriptor for people detection can be found at opencv_source_code/samples/cpp/peopledetect.cpp
>
> A GPU example applying the HOG descriptor for people detection can be found at opencv_source_code/samples/gpu/hog.cpp

You can then check if your moving objects are people or not, and decide whether ignore them or not.

Since you want to track cars, a simpler approach is based on the consideration that *a person is smaller than a car*, or that (with reference to their bounding boxes) *for a person usually the height is greater than the width* (usually a person is standing or walking), *for a car is the other way around*. You can apply simple geometric constraints to ignore what should be a person.

- You can set the maximum area of the bounding box of a person according to your camera resolution and view. Let's call this area value `maxAreaPerson` Then for every moving object you get the bounding box (you probably already do that, or just use `boundingRect(...)`). If the box area is smaller than `maxAreaPerson`, you ignore it.
- Instead of defining the max area, you can define the max width, height, aspect ratio, or a combination of them.
- Probably your objects are smaller if far from camera. Aspect ratio would be useful since it's not affected by the distance of the object with respect to the camera. Or you can define a few zones in your view (e.g. near camera, far from camera, very far from camera) and define your constraint for each zone.