# Overlapping in object detection in Opencv

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, overlapping, canny-operator

I am using opencv and visual studio ultimate 2010. My goal is to detect cars in a road and count them. I am using edge detection solution for this.

1. Does any one have any idea for detecting,counting and speed computing?
2. What is the solution for overlapping cars (for counting)?

We want to perform this tasks for any object that cross of virtual line.

Comment: You need to be more specific. As is, the question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: thank you.i am new to opencv.i have a video file of a camera that record road traffic i want to process this video and extract some parameter of it such counting cars ,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is still to broad.

However, I'll try to give you some pointers.

1. You can use a background subtraction method. You can find some info and code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31432220/5008845) and [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html). The work on your moving objects (cars). You can find some hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31504088/5008845)
2. Setup you *car classifier* , and try to detect the cars in your scene. You can find a nice tutorial on Support Vector Machine (SVM) [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html), or you can start from the [OpenCV people detector](https://github.com/smart-make/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/peopledetect.cpp) example, training it to detect cars instead of people.

For counting cars I recommend the first approach.

Good luck!

Comment: in end of project, i want to predict traffic volume, average ,maximum and minimum speed in the road and recognition of each vehicle like truck,motorbike and etc.